# MySQL Connector/Net executing extra actions on database servers while running simple select statements

Tags: c#, mysql-connector, newrelic

I'm currently using [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), with a C# .NET web services.

I'm doing performance tuning for my webservices and found out that all my mysql call from my web services (even simple select statement) will execute few extra "actions".

I'm executing this `"select * from TABLE_ABC"` simple select statements, and when i go to

```
     [NewRelic][2] --> App Server --> Web Transactions --> click on one of the
 transactions --> "Performance breakdown" tab
```

I see the following breakdown, there are 3 actions (in bold text) done on the database.

```
(DotNet) MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()<br>
    (DotNet) System.Web.HttpApplication+MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.
HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()<br>
    (Database) TABLE_ABC - SELECT<br>
```

**(Database) variables - SHOW**
**(Database) collation - SHOW**

```
(DotNet) System.Web.Services.Protocols.SyncSessionlessHandler.ProcessRequest()<br>
```

**(Database) character_set_results - SET**

```
(DotNet) WebService.MyServices.GetData()<br>
```

Normal PHP codes doing this select statement won't show the 3 extra actions.

Is it by design for MySQL Connector/Net or there is way for me to skip this?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone is looking for the answer.

[Answer on MySQL forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,569351,569351#msg-569351)